# Determine if a certificate is installed using CN (via powershell 2.0)?

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have a PS 2.0 script that needs to check if a few certificates are installed.  I tried this but it didn't work...

```
if(Test-Path cert:\LocalMachine\My\mycert1.mydomain.com)
{Write-Host "cert is installed"}
```

I can do a test-path for the thumbprint, but I want to check if it is installed by the common name...?

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this can work for you?

```
[bool](dir cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | ? { $_.subject -like "cn=localho*" })
```

Comment: That's a good start, thank you - what if I wanted to add a wildcard after the "cn=locahost"?  I'm only interested in matching the beginning of the CN...

Comment: @DominicBrunetti Edit my answer to fit your need, using -like that accept wildcards